# I cannot seem to run this properly... It stucks and does not display an output

Tags: performance, bash, loops, while-loop

Here's my script:

```
while [[ $startTime -le $endTime ]]
do

thisfile=$(find * -type f | xargs grep -l $startDate | xargs grep -l $startTime)
fordestination=`cut -d$ -f2 $thisfile | xargs cut -d ~ -f4`

echo $fordestination

startTime=$(( $startTime + 1 ))

done
```

Comment: it gets the user date and time input then will look for a specific while matching those inputs and outputs $fordestination..

Answer (score 1):

I think your cut and grep commands could get stuck. You probably should make sure that their parameters aren't empty, by using the `[ -n "$string" ]` command to see if `$string` isn't empty. In your case, if it were empty, it wouldn't add any files to the command that would use it afterwards, meaning that the command would probably wait for input from the command line (ex: if `$string` is empty and you do `grep regex $string`, grep wouldn't receive input files from `$string` and would instead wait for input from the command line). Here's a "complex" version that tries to show where things could go wrong:

```
while [[ $startTime -le $endTime ]]
do

thisfile=$(find * -type f)
if [ -n "$thisfile" ]; then
    thisfile=$(grep -l $startDate $thisfile)
    if [ -n "$thisfile" ]; then
        thisfile=$(grep -l $startTime $thisfile)
        if [ -n "$thisfile" ]; then
            thisfile=`cut -d$ -f2 $thisfile`

            if [ -n "$thisfile" ]; then
                forDestination=`cut -d ~ -f4 $thisfile`
                echo $fordestination
            fi
        fi
    fi
fi

startTime=$(( $startTime + 1 ))

done
```

And here's a simpler version:

```
while [[ $startTime -le $endTime ]]
do

thisfile=$(grep -Rl $startDate *)
[ -n "$thisfile" ] && thisfile=$(grep -l $startTime $thisfile)

[ -n "$thisfile" ] && thisfile=`cut -d$ -f2 $thisfile`
[ -n "$thisfile" ] && cut -d ~ -f4 $thisfile

startTime=$(( $startTime + 1 ))

done
```

The "-R" tells grep to search files recursively, and the `&&` tells bash to only execute the command that follows it if the command before it succeeded, and the command before the `&&` is the test command (used in `if`s).

Hope this helps =)

Comment: may i ask what's the use of printf "%s\\n"?

Comment: Sure. Sorry for the excessive editing, I misunderstood what you were trying to do, so the first version with the `printf` was a bit incorrect. The `printf` command is similar to the printf function in C. It is used instead of `echo "$bla"` because if `$bla` started with a hyphen (`-`), echo would interpret as an option, and not the string to be printed. That's why it's safer to use `printf %s//n "$bla"` when the string you want to print starts with a variable.